# Remove duplicate values from pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am analyzing stack overflow survey data. One of the columns `Databaseworkedwith` is a semicolon separated list of values so I used split and then explode to create new row for each value. But now I am getting duplicates values for other column. Is there a way to not to duplicate other column and instead have null in them.

Below is my code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

if __name__ == '__main__':

    session = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("StackOverFlow Developer Survey").getOrCreate()

    options = {"header":"true" , "inferSchema":"true"}
    initialDF = session.read.options(**options).csv("E:\\DataProject\\developer_survey_2020\\survey_results_public.csv")

    initialDF.show()

    demographicsDF = initialDF.select("Respondent","Age","Age1stCode","Country","EdLevel","Gender","Sexuality")

    #demographicsDF.show()

    databaseworkedwithDF = initialDF.select("Respondent","DatabaseWorkedWith","DatabaseDesireNextYear")

    databaseworkedwithDF = databaseworkedwithDF.withColumn("DatabaseWorkedWith2" , f.split("DatabaseWorkedWith",";")) \
                            .withColumn("DatabaseDesireNextYear2",f.split("DatabaseDesireNextYear",";"))

    databaseworkedwithDF = databaseworkedwithDF.withColumn("DatabaseWorkedWith2" , f.explode("DatabaseWorkedWith2")) \
                            .withColumn("DatabaseDesireNextYear2" , f.explode("DatabaseDesireNextYear2"))

    databaseworkedwithDF.show(truncate=False)
```

And the output

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|Respondent|DatabaseWorkedWith                       |DatabaseDesireNextYear|DatabaseWorkedWith2 |DatabaseDesireNextYear2|
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|1         |Elasticsearch;Microsoft SQL Server;Oracle|Microsoft SQL Server  |Elasticsearch       |Microsoft SQL Server   |
|1         |Elasticsearch;Microsoft SQL Server;Oracle|Microsoft SQL Server  |Microsoft SQL Server|Microsoft SQL Server   |
|1         |Elasticsearch;Microsoft SQL Server;Oracle|Microsoft SQL Server  |Oracle              |Microsoft SQL Server   |
|2         |NA                                       |NA                    |NA                  |NA                     |
|3         |NA                                       |NA                    |NA                  |NA                     |
|4         |NA                                       |NA                    |NA                  |NA                     |
```

`DatabaseDesireNextYear2` column is repeated instead. Can it be null for second and third row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `posexplode` and mask the values in the other columns with null if the `pos` is not equal to 0:

```
# Example dataframe
df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
|Respondent|DatabaseWorkedWith                       |DatabaseDesireNextYear|
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
|1         |Elasticsearch;Microsoft SQL Server;Oracle|Microsoft SQL Server  |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+


import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    '*', 
    F.posexplode(F.split('DatabaseWorkedWith', ';')).alias('pos', 'DatabaseWorkedWith2')
).select(
    *[F.when(F.col('pos') == 0, F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns], 
    'DatabaseWorkedWith2'
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|Respondent|DatabaseWorkedWith                       |DatabaseDesireNextYear|DatabaseWorkedWith2 |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|1         |Elasticsearch;Microsoft SQL Server;Oracle|Microsoft SQL Server  |Elasticsearch       |
|null      |null                                     |null                  |Microsoft SQL Server|
|null      |null                                     |null                  |Oracle              |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```